# Image gallery from folder with limit of images

Tags: php, html, modx

I have some code below, but I cant get the array_splice to limit the number of images shown.

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
  if (empty($id)) { 
    $clientname = 'tazz';
} else {
    $clientname = $_GET['id'];
}

$total = $_GET['limit'];
  if (empty($total)) { 
    $limit = '100';
} else {
    $limit = $_GET['limit'];
}

$basefolder = "client/client-galleries/";
$dirname = $basefolder.$clientname."/";

    $images = scandir($dirname);
    sort($images);
    //shuffle($images);
    $ignore = array(".", "..");
    $output = array_splice($ignore, 0, $limit);

foreach($images as $curimg) {
        if(!in_array($curimg, $output)) {

echo "
    <div class='gallery'>
        <img src='[[pThumb? &input=`$dirname$curimg` &options=`&w=300&h=300&zc=1&q=95&fltr[]=wmi|./client/images/gallery-watermark-white.png|BL|50|25|200`]]' alt='$curimg'>
        <div class='desc'></div>
    </div>\n ";

        }
    }
```

This correctly shows the images in the gallery but doesnt limit the amount of images as set by http://website.address?id=client&limit=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not applying `array_splice` to your `$images` array, but to your `$ignore` array, which only contains `"."` and `".."`. Also, `array_splice` is used to search/replace within an array, you're probably looking for `array_slice`, which is used to get a specific part of an array.

If you use `array_diff` to remove unwanted values from `$images`, you can then use `array_slice` to only keep at most `$limit` images. Something like this:

```
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = array(".", "..");
$images_filtered = array_diff($images, $ignore);
$images_limited = array_slice($images_filtered, 0, $limit);
```

`$images_filtered` should contain all items from `$images` that are not in `$ignore`.
`$images_limited` should contain the first `$limit` items from `$images_filtered`.

Comment: Thanks a heap @rickdenhann Id been looking at this for so long I didn't even pick that up.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with your code, such as using the $ignore array instead of your $images array. I've made a few changes which is probably closer to what you're after.

```
$limit = 5;
$dirname = "...";
$images = array_diff(scandir($dirname), [".", ".."]);
sort($images);
$limitedImages = array_slice($images, 0, 5);
foreach ($limitedImages as $curimg) {
   var_dump($curimg);
}
```